# how to preselect an option of a dropdown list with symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

An aticle has several variables.  A title, a date, visibility and a category.  If i render a form with symfony, i want to preselect a category in the dropdownlist. In the controller i have a function :

```
/**
 * @return Response
 * @route ("/admin/add/{idartikeltype}",name="addbytype")
 */
public function addByType(Request $request, $idartikeltype)
{


    $form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class);


    $form->handleRequest($request);



    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $item = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('lookup');
    }


    return $this->render('backend/add.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView(),));
}
```

The slug idartikeltype, an integer, contains the id of the category.  How must i preselect the correct category in a blanc form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the item first, set the category and then use it in the form:

```
$category = $this->em->getRepository(Category::class)->find($categoryId);

$item = new Item();
$item->setCategory($category);

$form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class, $item);
```

Comment: "Entity of type ... must be managed, did u forget to persist it in the enity manager " when i create an object of the Categroy typeand pass it to the $item variable.

Comment: @A You don't create a new category. You need to get the category by its id. I updated my answer.